# jQuery click on datatable not work after 10 record

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm having a trouble to run a jquery datatable. The href link doesn't run after the 10th record. Please help me to solve this problem

Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var oTable1 = $('#sample-table-1').dataTable( {
        "aoColumns": [
                  { "bSortable": false },
                  null,null,null,null,null,


                  { "bSortable": false }
         ] } );

        $(".kode").click(function(){
             var idDetail = $(this).data('id');
             var judul = "ID Pengaduan: " + idDetail;
             $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo site_url();?>/laporan/pencariandetail",
                type:"POST",
                data:({detail:idDetail}),
                success: function(html){
                    $('#tampildetail').html(html);
                    $('.modal-title').text(judul);
                    $("#myModal2").modal("show");
                }
            });

      });

});
</script>
```

Here's the view

```
<tbody>
            <?php
            <td><a href="#" class="kode" id="kode" data-id="<?php echo $row->IDPengaduan; ?>"><?php echo $row->IDPengaduan; ?></a></td>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant get what you are about to say. Where is your **a href** link. Wether you are using  ajax datatable to load after 10 records?

From my prespective if `".kode"` is your a tag then after ajax success you should **redraw** your table

```
success: function(html){
                        $('#tampildetail').html(html);
                        $('.modal-title').text(judul);
                        $("#myModal2").modal("show");
                        oTable1();
                    }
```